# DataGridView Rows Count 0 After Event Handler

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowcount, eventhandler

I have run into a very strange issue dynamically building a DataGridView and a group of radio buttons.  I have a group of radio buttons and a DataGridView inside of a Panel. The issue I am running into is I am trying to get the number of rows in the DataGridView using an event handler on some radio buttons.  The DataTable I am using has 3 rows.  You can recreate this problem manually adding rows to the DGV, it doesn't matter.  When I call the rows.count after I initialize the DataGridView it works as planned and returns 3 but when an EventHandler is fired the row count returned is 0.  My code is as follows:

```
    private DataSet testData;
    private DataTable testDataTable;

    public Form1(API _api)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        api = _api;
        businessLayer = new BusinessLayer();

        testData = api.getDataSet();
        testDataTable = businessLayer.getDataTable(testData);

        buildDataGridView();

    }

    // Build the DataGridView
    private void buildDataGridView()
    {
        int numOfRows = testDataTable.Rows.Count;

        DataGridView testDataGridView = new DataGridView();
        testDataGridView.Columns.Add("Description", "");
        testDataGridView.Columns.Add("Name", "");
        testDataGridView.Rows.Add(numOfRows);
        testDataGridView.Location = new Point(150, 20);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
        {
            RadioButton rbutton = new RadioButton();
            rbutton.Name = testDataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("Name").ToString() + "RadioButton";
            rbutton.Text = testDataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("Name");
            rbutton.Tag = testDataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("SortOrder");
            rbutton.CheckedChanged += rbutton_CheckedChanged;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                rbutton.Checked = true;
            }
            rbutton.Location = new Point(5, 20 * (i + 1));
            testPanel.Controls.Add(definition);
        }

        testPanel.Controls.Add(testDataGridView);

        textBox1.Text = testDataGridView.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }

    // RadioButton CheckChanged EventHandler
    private void definition_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
        if(rb.Checked)
        {
            textBox1.Text = testDataGridView.Rows.Count.ToString();

        }
    }
```

This has really got me confused but if I figure it out I am bound to learn something here.  I don't know if this has something to do with the fact that the DGV and the radio buttons are inside of a Panel, I don't know...Thanks for any help with this and helping me learn!

Comment: `...laborLevelsDataGridView...testDataGridView...`

Comment: typo...forgot to rename that instance of laborLevelsDataGridView to testDataGridView.  If you rename laborLevels to test you will see the behavior I am describing still exists

Answer (score 0):

As Grant Winney explained in a comment the DataGridView referenced in buildDataGridView() and the one referenced in definition_CheckedChanged() are not the same...an example of memory heap and memory stack. Here is a more simple example of what I was trying to do:

```
public partial class TestingForm2 : Form
{
    private DataTable testDataTable;
    // Must Declare here so the value is stored in heap memory
    // so other functions can access and use the value
    private DataGridView testDataGridView;

    public TestingForm2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        buildDataTable();
        buildDataGridView();
        buildRadioButtons();
    }

    private void buildRadioButtons()
    {
        int numOfRadioButtons = testDataTable.Rows.Count;

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfRadioButtons; i++)
        {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
            rb.Name = testDataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("Name") + "RadioButton";
            rb.Text = testDataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("Name");
            rb.Tag = testDataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("Number");

            if(i == 0)
            {
                rb.Checked = true;
            }

            rb.Location = new Point(5, 20 * (i + 1));
            rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged;
            panel1.Controls.Add(rb);
        }

    }

    private void buildDataGridView()
    {
        // Get number of rows in testDataTable
        int numOfRows = testDataTable.Rows.Count;

        // Build the empty DGV
        // If I were to declare the DGV here the value given would have
        // been stored in the memory stack and could only be accessed by
        // this function.  This is where I went wrong and made a silly mistake
        testDataGridView = new DataGridView();
        testDataGridView.Columns.Add("Name", "");
        testDataGridView.Columns.Add("Number", "");
        testDataGridView.Rows.Add(numOfRows);
        testDataGridView.Location = new Point(150, 20);
        testDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        testDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        testDataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        testDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        testDataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        testDataGridView.MultiSelect = false;
        testDataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        testDataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;

        panel1.Controls.Add(testDataGridView);
    }

    private void buildDataTable()
    {
        testDataTable = new DataTable();

        // Add the Columns
        testDataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
        testDataTable.Columns.Add("Number");

        // Create and add the rows
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            // Create the new row
            DataRow dr;
            object[] rowItems = new object[testDataTable.Columns.Count];

            if (i == 0)
            {
                rowItems[0] = "Bob";
                rowItems[1] = "1";
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                rowItems[0] = "John";
                rowItems[1] = "2";
            }
            else
            {
                rowItems[0] = "George";
                rowItems[1] = "3";
            }

            // Add the row
            dr = testDataTable.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = rowItems;
            testDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }

    private void TestingForm2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = testDataGridView.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = testDataGridView.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }

    private void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
        int index = int.Parse(rb.Tag.ToString()) - 1;
        if (rb.Checked)
        {
            testDataGridView.Rows[index].Selected = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Sorry for the mistake everyone! Thanks for the help!